# How to retrieve all taxonomy term using json api

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I want to retrieve all  taxonomy term name using json api.

I have tried:

```
http://local-tes/jsonapi/taxonomy_term/specialties
```

but its only return 50 values, I want to fetch  all taxonomy terms values.

Comment: I believe this is capped so the application doesn't crash from loading hundreds+ of potential entities. You'll need to loop and paginate over it or use a contrib module that increases the number returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://www.drupal.org/docs/core-modules-and-themes/core-modules/jsonapi-module/pagination#s--cant-i-set-a-page-limit-higher-than-50:

> **Why can't I set a page limit higher than 50?**
>
> First, read the example given above. Understand that JSON:API must run
> individual access checks for every entity in a response. Second,
> understand that the JSON:API module aims to be "zero configuration."
> You shouldn't have to install, alter or configure anything to use the
> module.
>
> The reason for this is to protect your application from a DDoS attack.
> If a malicious API client set a page limit of 200,000 resources, the
> JSON:API module would need to run entity access checks for every one
> of those entities. This would quickly lead to out-of-memory errors and
> slow responses. The server needs to set a maximum. The limit of 50 was
> somewhat arbitrarily chosen as a nice round number.
>
> Please understand that there have been many long conversations around
> this decision and a compromise had to be made between support burden,
> sane defaults, and frontend performance. While the JSON:API module
> maintainers do understand that this may not be ideal for every use
> case, they're confident that if your client follows the
> recommendations in these docs, it should have little to no impact on
> you :)

There is the [JSON:API Page Limit](https://www.drupal.org/project/jsonapi_page_limit) module and also JSON API Defaults (part of the popular [JSON:API Extras](https://www.drupal.org/project/jsonapi_extras) module) to change the limit.

After you have installed the JSON API Defaults module go to

[http://example.com/admin/config/services/jsonapi/add/resource_types/taxonomy_term/[vocabulary]](http://example.com/admin/config/services/jsonapi/add/resource_types/taxonomy_term/%5Bvocabulary%5D)

and change the page limit at the bottom of the config form.

Then you can request a higher number of items with the query parameter `page[limit]`:

[http://example.com/jsonapi/taxonomy_term/[vocabulary]?page[limit]=1000](http://example.com/jsonapi/taxonomy_term/%5Bvocabulary%5D?page%5Blimit%5D=1000)